# How to Batch Update Channel Preferences?

Tags: mysql, channel-preferences, batch-update, queries

I inherited a site with a zillion channels, and every channel has "Automatically Convert URLs to Links?" set to "yes".

Is there a query I can use to update the preferences for all of these channels to "no" at the same time?

EE 2.5.2

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following should work:

```
UPDATE exp_channels SET channel_auto_link_urls = 'n';
```

Backup your DB first though! Always better to be safe.

---

**Update:**

My answer assumes that you know about the Database Query Form. It's located in Tools » Data » SQL Manager » Database Query Form.

---

**Further Update:**

Removed backtick quotes from around table / column names for strange instances where that might cause an SQL error. :-)

Comment: Could you edit your answer to remove the quotes around the table names? It was causing a SQL error for me.

Comment: @kgrote - Done!